# Android SD card storing checking using Emulator

Tags: android

I am storing the information in a file in SD card in Android applicaiton. Can i check in emulator whether the information is correctly storing in sd card?

Comment: are you want to check where the file you stored on sdcard in emulator or how to check

Comment: if u want to check whether the contents u are storing are right or not then u can also pull the file and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

1. First u need to Run your App.
2. Then Goto Window->ShowView->File Explorer
3. open File Explorer tab on right hand side.
4. expand tree structure. mnt/sdcard/
5. Select your File and on TopMost bar of File Explorer, u will find two buttons for 'Pull/Push a File from Device'. Select that.

And it will be on your computer. Hope it is what you want.